# Generating reports at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc, report

I want to to generate a `Microsoft Report(.rdlc)` in C# with dynamic columns at the time of report generation . I mean not by selecting any column from database table at the time of `Microsoft Report(.rdlc)` design. Instead of that passing an SQl query string and get the `Microsoft Report(.rdlc)` dynamically at runtime in ASP.net C#.

Is there any tutorial which will guide me how do i proceed with this? I an very new to Reports and it is getting difficult for me even to search google regarding my query.

Hope someone guides me to help me generate reports.Any tutorial or useful link with source code would be very helpful.

Report outlook

[image]

Comment: If you're trying to create a crosstab ("pivot") report then there are easier ways - if not, good luck!

Comment: crosstab ("pivot") report meaning? i did not understand.

Comment: You might as well introduce to the user the Report Builder of SSRS, it might be helpful to them by giving them only the models and decide what fields to show in the report.

Comment: @Ishan - Suppose you want to show products down the left-hand side of the report and months across the top, with sales figures in the cells.  This is a crosstab report - the columns would be built up by the reporting engine based on the month(s) in your data.

Comment: @ Will A Exactly what i want but instead of months i want Some CATEGORIES and below that some CASENUMBER retrieved from database.

Comment: @Ishan - I hope you'll find my answer gives you what you need without the hassle of creating .rdlcs on the fly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following link for generating RDLC dynamically. 
[http://csharpshooter.blogspot.com/2007/08/revised-dynamic-rdlc-generation.html](http://csharpshooter.blogspot.com/2007/08/revised-dynamic-rdlc-generation.html.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [ReportViewer Control](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Adding a Matrix (Reporting Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157334.aspx) for a guide on how to add a pivot-table style grid to your report.

Comment: From where should i add Matrix Control?

Comment: From the Toolbox in BIDS - the same place you'd insert a Table.

Comment: No problem - BIDS is VS.Net, pretty much - based on the same 'shell' application at least.